# How can I use Stack Overflow tags in my profile?

Tags: discussion

I'd like to bind Stack Overflow tags to my profile for filtering the listings of posts. Is it possible?

Comment: See "Add favorite and ignored tags" here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/interesting-topics

Comment: What you want used to be possible during testing of a new layout, but work on that new layout was abandoned. Currently you can only execute a manual search with a bunch of tags, see the duplicate.